# Getting Error POST http://localhost:8080/stub/cms/myalerts2.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, cors, grunt-contrib-connect

I am running my application with grunt task runner, it throws me following error:

**POST http://localhost:8080/stub/cms/myalerts2.json 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

I have tried following things in my Gruntfile.js

```
 connect: { 
                server: { 
                    options: { 
                        keepalive: true, 
                        port: 8001, 
                        protocol: 'http', 
                        hostname: '*', 
                        base: 'dis', 
                        directory: 'dis', 
                        open: { 
                            target: 'http://localhost:8001/mydemo.html', 
                            appname: 'open' 
                        },

                        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {
                    middlewares.unshift(function(req,res,next){
                            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
                            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE');
                            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', req.headers['access-control-request-headers']);
                        });
                        return middlewares;
                }   
} 
        } 
    },
```

Still its not allowing me to run. Any help or suggestion will me most welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: is this a typo, or did you use port `8080` in the URI and port `9001` in the code on purpose?

Comment: ok after your edit you now you have *three* different ports, `8080`, `8001`, and `9001`.

Comment: Sorry @claies its running on 8001 only

Comment: `405 method not allowed` usually means the resource you are trying to access doesn't support the method (`POST`, in this case), which would probably make sense, since you can't `POST` to a `.json` file.....  What is it you are *actually* trying to accomplish here, exactly?

Comment: @Claies, thanks for your update, i wanted to access json files via POST. Currently i am getting following error:-  Error: `value` required in setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value).
   at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:342:11)
   at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (D:\GN\NavigationAtt\node_modules\karma\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:134:22)
   at D:\GN\NavigationAtt\Gruntfile.js:255:13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of irritating days finally my code works for me. Look into my code below:-

```
connect: { 
            server: { 
                options: { 
                    keepalive: true, 
                    port: 8001, 
                    protocol: 'http', 
                    hostname: '*', 
                    directory: 'dist', 
                    open: { 
                        target: 'http://localhost:8001/myDemo.html', 

                    },
                        middleware: function(connect, options, middlewares) {

                                middlewares.unshift(function(req, res, next) {
                                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                                    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                                    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
                                    **if (req.method.toUpperCase() == 'POST') req.method='GET';**
                                    return next();
                                });

                                return middlewares;
                        }

                } 
            } 
        },
```

see the star marked line ie `if (req.method.toUpperCase() == 'POST') req.method='GET';` i done this trick and its worked for me.
This aricle also helps to me https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect#middleware

Answer (score 0):

So far i have tried following updation to my code, i am able to get rid of Method not Allowed 405 Error but currently i am getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"
i have modified my code as below:-

```
connect: { 
            server: { 
                options: { 
                    keepalive: true, 
                    port: 8001, 
                    protocol: 'http', 
                    hostname: '*', 
                    base: 'dist', 
                    directory: 'dist', 
                    open: { 
                        target: 'http://localhost:8001/myDemo.html', 
                        appname: 'open' 
                    },
                        middleware: function(connect, options, next) {
                              return [
                                function(req, res, next) {
                                 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
                                 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                                 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
                                 next();
                              }];
                        }

                } 
            } 
        },
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.